# Цикл для слайдера картинок bootstrap

Tags: django, python-3.x

Здравствуйте. На главную страницу 'base.html' хочу вывести слайдер изображений по три блока.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код bootstrap (сама разметка):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div id='imageCarousel' class="carousel slide" data-interval='3000' data-ride='carousel'>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
            <!-- Первый блок из трех слайдов -->
                <!-- Первый элемент должен иметь класс active -->
                <div class='item active'>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <img src='http://m1.daumcdn.net/cfile203/original/2558E1445323B75C333A4C' class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-xs-4'>
                        <img src='http://i.imgur.com/ADpnVqL.jpg?fb' class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-xs-4'>
                        <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT0hQax-qRSiMYXBXXGy3sxNIMaAuMZTWbBWGUczG0tGyNe_c5kwA' class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <!-- Второй блок из трех слайдов -->
                <div class='item'>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <img src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-xIsQRVcjvAc/VtQn9SAws7I/AAAAAAAAAJc/mdtp88w4Nb4/w506-h750/LION-RAINBOW-ART.jpg' class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-xs-4'>
                        <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTas2u0NIPpYQpLAE8G2rjOui8ntxRVgPFmeKhUj0xub0Elg50q' class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-xs-4'>
                        <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSyLwR9OozPx5YReXWRcwk5e1ysWf8lts3xLrxmlmkTnVXvoqxM' class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Цикл:

```
<div class='item'>
{% for obj in img_list %}  
    <div class='col-xs-4'>                      
        <img src='{{ obj.image.url|safe }}' class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Необходимо, чтобы цикл пробегал по всем изображением и группировал их по три, оборачивая в нужные теги.

В 'base.html':

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id='imageCarousel' class="carousel slide" data- 
            interval='3000' data-ride='carousel'>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class='item active'>
                    {% include 'partners.html' %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Посоветуйте решение. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, который первый пришел в голову - отдавать в шаблон список списков, т.е `img_list = [[img1,img2, img3], [img4,img5,img6]...]` и затем уже:

```
{% for obj in img_list %}
   <div class='item'>
    {% for el in obj %}
      <div class='col-xs-4'>                      
          <img src='{{ el.image.url|safe }}' class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```